# Changing value from 0 to 'UNKNOWN'

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a SQL query similar to the one shown below

```
SELECT col1 AS 'Column 1', SUM(ROUND(col2, 2)) AS 'Column 2'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY col1
```

This is run in a PHP script, and is used to generate JSON. Column 1 is a float type, and a large chunk of the data in Column 1 is 0. I would like it so that whenever a value in Column 1 is 0, it replaces it with `UNKNOWN`. For example. The query I have above will output something like so

```
------------------------------
|0            |142563        |
------------------------------
|1            |348           |
------------------------------
|2            |2535          |
------------------------------
|3            |32            |
------------------------------
|4            |82536         |
------------------------------
|5            |12            |
------------------------------
```

I would like it to be like this

```
------------------------------
|UNKNOWN      |142563        |
------------------------------
|1            |348           |
------------------------------
|2            |2535          |
------------------------------
|3            |32            |
------------------------------
|4            |82536         |
------------------------------
|5            |12            |
------------------------------
```

Can someone help me out? Thanks!

Comment: Why are you using UKNOWN instead of NULL?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You want to use the `case` statement:

```
SELECT (case when col1 = 0 then 'Unknown' else cast(col1 as varchar(255)) end) AS 'Column 1', 
       SUM(ROUND(col2, 2)) AS 'Column 2'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY col1;
```

I also included an explicit `cast()`, because `col1` is a float.

If you want to control the format, use `str()`.  Perhaps:

```
SELECT (case when col1 = 0 then 'Unknown' else str(col1, 6, 2) end) AS 'Column 1', 
       SUM(ROUND(col2, 2)) AS 'Column 2'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY col1;
```

Answer (score 2):

Use TSQL `CASE` statement

```
SELECT CASE WHEN col1 = 0 THEN 'Unknown' ELSE Col1 END AS 'Column 1', SUM(ROUND(col2, 2)) AS 'Column 2'
FROM db.dbo.table
GROUP BY col1
```

Comment: This did not work. `Error converting data type varchar to float`

Answer (score 0):

In SQL Server 2012, you can do

```
SELECT IIF(col1 = 0, 'UNKNOWN', cast(col1 as varchar(100)))AS 'Column 1', SUM(ROUND(col2, 2)) AS 'Column 2' 
FROM table
GROUP BY col1;
```